# How to complete CI/CD pipelines with Azure DevOps for Azure API Management

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management

I need help to understand better how to create  complete CI/CD with Azure Devops for APim. Ok I already has explored the tools and read docs:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit

But I still have questions, my scenario:
APim dev instance with APi and operations created and others settings, as well APim prod instance created but empty.
I ran the extract tool and got the templates (not all), still need the Master (linked templates), and on this point seat my doubt, I already have 2 repos too(dev and prod).

How can I create the Master template, and how my changes from dev environment will be automatically applied to prod? 
I didn't used the policyXMLBaseUrl parameters not sure what Path insert there, although seems @miaojiang inserted a folder from azure storage.

Answer (score 1):

After some search and tries I deployed API's and Operations from an environment to another, but we still don't have a full automated scenario, where I make a change in a instance and that is automatically available.Is necessary to edit policies and definitions directly on the repositories or run the extract tool again.

Comment: Can you explain how you did it?

Comment: Hey @CarlosGarcia , so already some time that I did it, but I'm thinking in write a tutorial about it, What do you think ? But basically I followed the documentation.